# Google Assistant / Dialogflow Back Press Context

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-assistant, dialogflow-cx

```css
from pydialogflow_fulfillment import DialogflowResponse
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods = ['POST'])
def user():
    request_ = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(request_)
    qr = request_['queryResult']
    queryText = qr['queryText']
    querys = str(queryText)
    print("querys")
    print(querys)
    if (querys == "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME"):
        return{
      "payload": {
        "google": {
          "expectUserResponse": True,
          "richResponse": {
            "items": [
              {
                "simpleResponse": {
                  "textToSpeech": "Choose a item"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "systemIntent": {
            "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
            "data": {
              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
              "listSelect": {
                "title": "Hello",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "optionInfo": {
                      "key": "first title key"
                    },
                    "description": "first description",
                    "image": {
                      "url": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
                      "accessibilityText": "first alt"
                    },
                    "title": "first title"
                  },
                  {
                    "optionInfo": {
                      "key": "second"
                    },
                    "description": "second description",
                    "image": {
                      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw",
                      "accessibilityText": "second alt"
                    },
                    "title": "second title"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    elif (querys == "actions_intent_OPTION"):
        request_ = request.get_json(force=True)
        # get json data in user request
        qr = request_['queryResult']
        print(request_)
        queryText = qr['queryText']
        querys = str(queryText)
        print("querys")
        print(querys)
        dialogflow_response = DialogflowResponse("you r selecting"+querys)
        print("Response:\n" +dialogflow_response.get_final_response())
        people = dialogflow_response.get_final_response()
        print(people)
        return people
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
OUTPUT:
querys
actions_intent_OPTION
Response:
{"fulfillmentText": "actions_intent_OPTION", "fulfillmentMessages": [], "source": "webhook", "outputContexts": [], "payload": {"google": {}}}
```

[screenshot](https://ibb.co/gv34vvS) [screenshot](https://ibb.co/p18z6c2)
Above my Code Have.I have a case where I can go back from in between conversation in Dialogflow, When tried in Google assistant, pressing back and selecting another option makes a google search instead of performing the reqired action. I am working with webhook fullfillment.

Example Scenario (same happens with me):

**Google Assistant:** shows list view "Choose a item"

**Me:** i select first title

**Google Assistant :** it shows "you r selecting first title" or"action_intent_OPTION"

**Me:** then i press back button

**Google Assistant :** Displays same List View (Choose a item)

**Me:** then i choose second title

**Google Assistant :** it shows "can i say that again?".

I need help with being within the context even after back press.

**Me:** i select first title

**Google Assistant :** it shows "you r selecting first title" or"action_intent_OPTION"

**Me:** when i choose second title

**Google Assistant :** you r selecting second title.

---

or

Is there a way to get any intents in between the conversation ?

Like, if I was in the middle of a conversation, say after 4-5 questions with google, and if I ask the second question, it is replying - "I missed that, say that again ?", instead i need the 2nd intent to work. (I have used follow up intents in this case)